# How do the Maven Multithread builds work?

Tags: multithreading, maven, build, parallel-processing

I've been looking around and would like some clarification regarding exactly how maven executes the build of a multi-module project when using the **-T** option.  On their [confluence page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3), they note that

> This build-mode analyzes your project's dependency graph and schedules modules that can be built in parallel according to the dependency graph of your project...

So to my understanding, if I execute mvn clean install -T 4 where I have modules A,B,C,D,E, and F such that

- A is dependent on B
- B is dependent on C
- and D is dependent on C

C, E, and F would all start off at the same time, and D and B would only start once C is finished with.  Is that correct?

My further question is: do the dependents (D and B) start as soon as its parent (C) is

1. finished compiling/installing but not necessarily done testing, or
2. done with everything including the testing?

**Info about my setup:** This has happened for me on both Maven 3.3.3 and Maven 3.1.1.  I'm currently using Java 1.7.0_79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the [graphic they start off are based on their levels](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3#ParallelbuildsinMaven3-HowExecutionisevaluated). So i assume that the Modules C, E and F would start first once all these modules (level 1) are finished the next level with modules B and D will start and finally module A.

The execution within a module is based on the life cycle which means a module will run all phases of the life cycle for example if you do `mvn -T 4 package` all modules will run all cycles including the package cycle.
If you run `mvn -T 4 install` all modules run all life cycle steps (which contains the test phase)...

The [smart-builder](http://takari.io/book/30-team-maven.html#takari-smart-builder) can make this faster in particular if you have a large number of modules.

Comment: I understand that each module will ultimately run through all phases of the life cycle, but my second question is really more about WHEN will it move on from one module to the next?  

For example, if I have 4 threads, and A B and C depend on D, will A B C have to wait until D is thoroughly finished? or will they start as soon as D is built (albeit not tested).

Comment: As i explained by the levels.

Comment: I'm not asking about the order, but rather the timing.  When can they move on and start the next?

Comment: As i mentioned if the level is finished the next level will start. May be i misunderstand the point you mean?

Comment: So it has to be fully finished with the maven goal for that level before it moves on?  I'm just triple checking here haha.  Thanks @khmarbaise